# Updating text file inside of Google Team Drive using Google Docs API- PowerShell

Tags: powershell, google-docs-api

I have a powershell script currently that pulls in data from a Google Sheet on a team drive and then creates Active Directory users in our environment based on that data. I haven't gotten to fully test this part yet, but don't believe it will cause me any problems.

Where I am having issues is I would like to use a Team-Shared Google Drive Document to contain all of my logging for this automation.

I have had no issues authenticating but cannot seem to get the POST request correct for batchUpdating the document itself. I am able to obtain the revision Id without any problem. I cannot seem to find out where to pass the "batchUpdate" object in my request. I am not worried about where the text is stored on the page once it is added, just looking to add the text to the file.

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate#http-request

Here is how I am obtaining my access token

```
function Get-Auth{
    #Obtains access token for the Google API's
    #Runs everytime to ensure there is a fresh access token available to the service account
    $refresh_body = @{

        client_id='338139966542-qaa4me7l4fs0l1ltl2e6kjidjr9tf3up.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        client_secret='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';
        refresh_token='1//04GjkX_q30ioyCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrKggdZo-Pq9E_t3qEbmhHmQe8JVVDW4vaXGoeFiRxxJ5KRu7f7TpQVDsHrwMdmc7Xqn4';
        grant_type="refresh_token";

    }
    #Makes a request to obtain the access token
    $refresh_token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token" -Method POST -Body $refresh_body

    $access_token = $refresh_token.access_token    
}
```

Here is where I am attempting to update the document

```
$document = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $access_token"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method GET -Uri "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1K8_q_VCTWin_s8aVb0D16DNujqA72eravHojMfM9cyo" 

$revId = $document.revisionId

$updateObject = {
  requests = [
    {
      insertText= {
        text= "The Red Dog Crosses the Road";
        endOfSegmentLocation= {
          segmentId= ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  writeControl= {
    requiredRevisionId= $revId;
  }
}


Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $access_token"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Uri "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1K8_q_VCTWin_s8aVb0D16DNujqA72eravHojMfM9cyo:batchUpdate" -Body $updateObject
```

Here is the error I receive when trying to make this request.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:39 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $access_token"}  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExceptio 
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I think I just need to find the correct place to put my *batchUpdate* object in the request, but I could be completely off. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification? I thought that the reason of your issue is due to the value of `$updateObject` and the request body of `-Body $updateObject`. In this case, the request body is required to be the string value. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

```bash
$document = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $access_token"} -Method GET -Uri "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1K8_q_VCTWin_s8aVb0D16DNujqA72eravHojMfM9cyo"
$revId = $document.revisionId
$updateObject = @{
  requests = @(
    @{
      insertText = @{
        text = "The Red Dog Crosses the Road";
        endOfSegmentLocation = @{
          segmentId = "";
        }
      }
    }
  )
  writeControl = @{
    requiredRevisionId = $revId;
  }
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $access_token"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Uri "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1K8_q_VCTWin_s8aVb0D16DNujqA72eravHojMfM9cyo:batchUpdate" -Body (ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 $updateObject)
```

#### Note:

- When this script is run, I confirmed that the text of "The Red Dog Crosses the Road" is appended to the Google Document.

#### Reference:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect.  If you don't mind me asking, what made you know that the request body needed to be a string value?? Makes sense looking at it but I was not quite sure how you determined that.

Comment: @RankinJ Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About ` what made you know that the request body needed to be a string value??`, in this case, I think that when you test ["Try this method"](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) by clicking the square button at the upper right, you can see that the request body is the string value. If this was not useful, I apologize.